# Can't create more than one table dynamically in android studio SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am trying to create more than one table dynamically in android studio SQLite database. I have attached my code below of two classes ***DatabaseHelper.java*** and ***DatabaseManager.java***. By running the below code, there is only one table were created.

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.circle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MY__2MESS11AGES.DB";
    public static String TABLE_NAME;
    public static String ID = "ID";
    public static String MESSAGE_ID = "MESSAGE_ID";
    public static String TIME_STAMP = "TIME_STAMP";
    public static String MESSAGE = "MESSAGE";
    public static String MESSAGE_STATUS = "MESSAGE_STATUS";
    public static String VIEW_TYPE = "VIEW_TYPE";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context,String table_name) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        TABLE_NAME = table_name;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME +"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,MESSAGE_ID TEXT,TIME_STAMP TEXT,MESSAGE TEXT,MESSAGE_STATUS TEXT NOT NULL,VIEW_TYPE TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

**DatabaseManager.java**

```
package com.example.circle;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DatabaseManager {

    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DatabaseManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public DatabaseManager open(String tableName) {
        System.out.println("DATA BASE MANAGER =================="+ tableName);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context, tableName);
        database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void insert(String tableName, String messageId, String timeStamp, String message, String messageStatus, String viewType) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.MESSAGE, message);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.MESSAGE_ID, messageId);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TIME_STAMP, timeStamp);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.MESSAGE_STATUS, messageStatus);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.VIEW_TYPE, viewType);
        database.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);
    }

    public Cursor fetch(String table_name) {
        String[] columns = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.ID, DatabaseHelper.MESSAGE_ID, DatabaseHelper.MESSAGE, DatabaseHelper.TIME_STAMP, DatabaseHelper.MESSAGE_STATUS, DatabaseHelper.VIEW_TYPE};
        Cursor cursor = database.query(table_name, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    public int update(String messageId, String tableName,String messageStatus){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.MESSAGE_STATUS,messageStatus);
        int ret = database.update(tableName,contentValues,DatabaseHelper.MESSAGE_ID + "=" + messageId,null);
        return ret;
    }

    public void close() {
        databaseHelper.close();
    }
}
```

And this is how I calling the constructor of **DatabaseManager.java** in my **MainActivity.java**

```
DatabaseManager databaseManager = new DatabaseManager(this);
String[]  tableName = {"sun", "moon", "one", "two", "four", "three", "five"}; //Name of the tables
 for(int i = 0 ;i<tableName.length ; i++){
        databaseManager.open(  tableName[i]);
        databaseManager.close();
}
```

Comment: It is not clear where the variable jabberId is coming from. Since its value is not specified in the code you shared, I'm assuming its length is zero, therefore your loop in MainActivity only runs once.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: *only one database* or *only one table*?

Comment: Need to create more than one table of same database.. The above code now creating only one table

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, onCreate only runs once, when the database is initially created:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)

Therefore it runs only one Create Table query. It would make more sense to put that loop with the table names inside the onCreate() method.